# C++ CRTP: How to make only one (some) function of the base class as a friend to to the derived class?

Tags: c++11, crtp, friend-function

I would like to make ONLY `Base<DerivedImpl>::fct1()` having access to  class `DerivedImpl` members.

Base looks like:

```
template < typename Derived>
class Base<Derived>{

protected:
void fct1(){
static_cast<Derived*>(this)->topfunc();
}

void fct2(){
...
}

};
```

Derived class looks like:

```
class DerivedImpl: public Base<DerivedImpl>{

void callbase(){fct1();}
void topfunc(){std::cout << "topfunc" <<std::endl;}

friend Base<DerivedImpl>; //this works
//friend void Base<DerivedImpl>::fct1(); //does not work!!
};
```

Main c++:

```
int main(){
DerivedImpl obj;
obj.callbase();
}
```

Comment: If you make `Base::fct1()` a `public` member function, you will be good to go.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks! However this force my base class to make its member pubic...

Comment: You'll have to make the call whether that is appropriate in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This answers the question as asked, but in my opinion, a different design approach is probably preferable, so I don't recommend you do this in production unless you absolutely have to.

You can work around this by abusing the fact that derived classes are allowed to access `protected` **static** members of their parent classes:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
class Base {
protected:
  static void fct1(Base* self){
    static_cast<Derived*>(self)->topfunc();
  }

  void fct2() {}
};

class DerivedImpl: public Base<DerivedImpl> {

  void callbase() { fct1(this); }
  void topfunc() { std::cout << "topfunc" << std::endl; }

  friend void Base<DerivedImpl>::fct1(Base*); // works fine now!
};
```